# additive group surjection and homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an additive group, and $u,v:G\to G$ be homomorphisms. Show that the map $f:G\to G$, $f(x)=x-v(u(x))$ is surjective if the map $h:G\to G$, $h(x)=x-u(v(x))$ is surjective.

My approach is like this : let $a\in G$, then $h(u(a))=u(a)-u(v(u(a)))=u(a-v(u(a)))=u(f(a))$, again $f(v(a))=v(a)-v(u(v(a)))=v(a-u(v(a)))=v(h(a))$. But after that how to get the surjectivity of $f$ using that of $h$?